# Keep Footer below dynamic content

Tags: css

so I'm trying to tame the Footer so that it stays below the dynamic content container, but whatever way I try it (Pos: Abs, Bottom: 0; etc etc) it either appears halfway up the content or fixed at the bottom. Either I don't want. It would be appreciated if someone could shine a light on my problem.

HTML:

```
<div id="Content">
    <div id="G6"></div>
    <div id="Post-Block">
        <div id="block">
            <div id="feat-img"></div>
            <div id="date"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Footer">
        <div id="G7"></div>
        <div id="FooterBreak"></div>
        <div id="FooterBG"></div>
        <div id="FooterLinks">
        </div>
        <div id="Copyright">
        </div>
        <div id="Copyright2">
        </div>
        <div id="FooterBreak2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 230px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#Content {
    z-index: 7;
    background: url(/images/content%20bg.jpg) repeat left top;
    position: absolute;
    top: 336px;
    width: 999px;
    height: auto;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 950px;
    margin: 0 0 230px;
}
html {
    position: relative;
    height: auto !important;
}
body {
    z-index: 0;
    background: url(/images/background-texture%20d.jpg);
    left: 0;
}
#page {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: You're using a lot of margin & padding. Your footer itself is right below your content. Can you please elaborate because it is not really clear to me...

Comment: @ThomasBormans You can see it live here, [link]http://crows-perch.com/blog/video-format-post/, the footer is halfway through the content, not right below it where there's the empty space (scroll down if you need to)

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Try [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: @Paulie_D I know, but I thought I'd give it a go -  I'm looking for specific help though.

Comment: Just remove all the positioning...close the 'content' div before you open the footer and the footer will **always** be below the content div. Simple really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: When I used the Chrome dev tools to inspect the Crow's Perch website, it looks like your problem is that the height of your HTML is smaller than your content (ie, you use negative bottom values in your absolute positioning for some of your content). Given this, you could add `bottom: -865` to #footer, but given that you said your content is dynamic, that's an EXTREMELY brittle solution. Unfortunately, since you're pixel-pushing all of your elements, I don't think there's a way to have your footer respond dynamically to your changing content. More comprehensive refactoring of your code is likely necessary.

Good luck!

Comment: Would you have a better alternative to pixel pushing? Also, is it just absolute positioning that is causing this error, or is there something else?

Comment: absolute positioning/pixel pushing itself isn't a deal breaker for what you're trying to do - it's the particular way you've gone about it that's causing the issues. Unfortunately I can't offer you a quick fix to solve the problem, but if you remove your set height on #page and remove your absolute positioning on #content, you'll see that the footer falls into place. That obviously breaks some of your other styling, but that at least gets you addressing the real problem, rather than searching for a hacky solution to the footer, which is really just a symptom of the real problem. Good luck!

Comment: Right, yep I see what you are talking about. Thanks for the help, now to fix all the styling issues!